# Update statement with IIF not upading

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, case-when, iif

I have a simple table with order-number, article-number and a rank:

```
select * from tbl_temp_ranked
```

[image]

I want to update another table only with rank=2. So I use the following update-statement

```
update hbs
set hbs.[2ND_NEXT_ORDER_Nr]=iif(ranked=2, ranked, null)
from TBL_HAKA_BASE_STAGE hbs
join tbl_temp_ranked tmp
on hbs.artikelnummer=tmp.artikelnummer
where hbs.Artikelnummer=115996
```

My target-table (TBL_HAKA_BASE_STAGE) is never updating. It only updates when I write

```
iif(ranked=1, ranked, null)
```

Only in that case my target table is updating! Writing `ranked<>1`, `ranked>1`, `ranked!=1`, `ranked=2` doesn't update my table. Same for `case when`-conditions in this `SET`-Statement. Casting didn't help also!

I could add this condition in my `WHERE`-statements, this helps, yes, but this short SQL-example is just a very short code in a large statement, so this is not a great solution for me. This would make me repeat all of the code over and over again.

Here are the structures for both tables, maybe it help

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_temp_ranked](
    [auftragsnummer] [float] NULL,
    [artikelnummer] [float] NULL,
    [ranked] [bigint] NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_HAKA_BASE_STAGE](

    [Artikelnummer] [float] NULL,
    [NEXT ORDER Nr] [float] NULL
)
```

It is SQL server 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicates in the "ranked" table.  I think you want a `left join`:

```
update hbs
    set hbs.[2ND_NEXT_ORDER_Nr] = tmp.ranked
    from TBL_HAKA_BASE_STAGE hbs left join
         tbl_temp_ranked tmp
         on hbs.artikelnummer = tmp.artikelnummer and tmp.ranked = 2
    where hbs.Artikelnummer = 115996;
```

Comment: Ah, yeah, now I understand... One line overwrites the second line.. It just accepts rank 1 because it is the last line which is updating.. Damn, this took me so much time... Thank you!